# Fixed table header scroll both horizontal and vertical CSS ONLY

Tags: html, css, scroll

Firstly, is it possible to achieve this using only CSS?

I have built a table that can scroll both horizontally and vertically however, I want to have the header encapsulated within it's container and not appear outside of the wrapper. So that when you scroll horizontally the corresponding header is in line with the content of it's designated column.

Using different variations of `position: absolute` and `position: static` give me some intended results but not the complete solution.

You'll note the width applied to the `section` element to give the effect of scrolling horizontally within the enclosed region.

Here is a JSFIDDLE example of what I have so far and CSS below to reference

https://jsfiddle.net/ko6qco1r/

```
html, body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  height:100%;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: grey;
  width: 300px;
}

.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  width:100%;
}
td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
th {
  height: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  color: transparent;
  border: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
th div{
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -25px;
  line-height: normal;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: The header stays in place, what is the problem?

Comment: Edited -  I want to have the header encapsulated within the it's container and not appear outside of the wrapper. So that when you scroll horizontally the corresponding header is in line with the content of it's designated column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another one of those *interesting* challenges (like vertical centering) brought to us by the inaction of the W3C. Also like vertical centering, you can't put a fixed header on a table with a horizontal scrollbar using `position: fixed;` on the `thead` element. But you do have a couple of options.

**Option 1 - Horizontal Scrolling** (http://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/JXbpvZ)

The key here is to reestablish your table layout as `table-layout: fixed;` [CSS-tricks has a good piece on this approach](https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/) and then put a `min-width` value on your container when you want the scrollbars to appear. This makes the table scrollable left to right and maintains the integrity of the column headers on smaller devices. But the header is not fixed.

**Option 2 - Fixed Header** (https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/)

Your code looked like a rip-off of this guy's work, so I thought I'd repost here to give him some credit. This approach creates a series of `<div>` elements that mirror the contents of the `<th>` elements and uses some VERY creative positioning techniques to get it all to work.

There is a much better run-down on [Salzar design](http://salzerdesign.com/blog/?p=191) that shows some [examples](http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html) and explains in detail all the complicated maneuvers to get this right.

Comment: Thanks for this and sadly this is what I've already arrived that - up to the business to decide what they want to do. As for ripping that guys code yes I did for the sake of an example - my actual code is different to his implementation as my table has a fixed left column that's done differently so thank you for noting that.

Comment: No worries - I think that's how you learn, at least that's how I do. Bad business requirements are something we all have to live with - carry on the good fight.