# React Material-Ui Sticky Table Header with Dynamic Height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material-UI framework for React to display a table. I would like to use a sticky header; however, I do not want to set a height on my table, as I'd like it to scroll with the page. The following snippet does not stick the header unless I set a height on the TableContainer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-firefly-5wlx2?file=/src/App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  TableContainer,
  Table,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  TableCell
} from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <TableContainer>
      <Table stickyHeader>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Value</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        {
          Array(100).fill("Test").map((e) => <TableRow><TableCell>{e}</TableCell></TableRow>)
        }
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Get rid of the `TableContainer` `overflow-x: auto` and it should work

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customTableContainer: {
    overflowX: "initial"
  }
})

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <TableContainer classes={{root: classes.customTableContainer}}>
      <Table stickyHeader>
      
      ...
```

[image: Edit cool-shadow-59lrh]

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/dealing-with-overflow-and-position-sticky/

Comment: Any way to do this while keeping 100% width?

Comment: i did not touch the `width` property of `TableContainer` - it is still at `100%` `width`. If you comment out the `overflowX: "initial"` on my code - you can see that it is still very similar to your sandbox, the only difference I made is on the sticky header

Comment: Let me rephrase: is there any way to keep the x direction scrollable within the table while making the y direction scrollable with the page - all while keeping the sticky header working.

Comment: It's quite possible. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977864/fixed-header-table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-and-vertical-scrollbar-on) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014802/fixed-table-header-scroll-both-horizontal-and-vertical-css-only)

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been looking for this fix for 2 days

Comment: I was having issues by wrapping my `<Table>` in a `<Card>` component. Building off the current answer, the solution worked for me:`<Card sx={{overflow:"inherit"}}>`, and of course `<Table stickyHeader>`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was facing something similar, I wanted my table to be 100% of the available height, so I gave 100% height to the parent tag instead of the table,  then in my table a made the calc of the parents height with my table's container reference, the implementation would be something like this

```js
// 1. create a ref
const tableContainerRef = useRef(null);

// 2. wait until the container ref is populated and retrieve the parents height
const containerMaxHeight = useMemo(() => {
  if (!tableFormRef.current) return null;

  return tableFormRef.current.parentElement.clientHeight;
}, [tableFormRef.current]);

// 3. use the height of the parent as your table's maxHeight
return (
  <div ref={tableContainerRef}>
    <TableContainer style={{maxHeight: containerMaxHeight}}>
      <Table>
       ...
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you just use `100vh` instead of `100%` it works:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: "100vh" }}>
      <Table stickyHeader>
```